# asp.net session variables to store all global data

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have inherited a project from a developer who was rather fond of session variables. He has used them to store all sorts of global stuff - datatables, datasets, locations of files, connection strings etc. I am a little worried that this may not be very scalable and we do have the possibility of a lot more users in the immediate future.

Am I right to be concerned, and if so why?
Is there an easy way to see how much memory this is all using on the live server at the moment?
What would be the best approach for re-factoring this to use a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would say that you do have some cause for concern. Overuse of session can cause a lot of performance issues. Ideally, session should only be used for information that is specific to the user. Obviously there are exceptions to this rule, but keep that in mind when you're refactoring.

As for the refactoring itself, I would look into caching any large objects that are *not* user-specific, and removing anything that doesn't need to be in session. Don't be afraid to make a few trips to the database to retrieve information when you need it. Go with the option that puts the least *overall* strain on the server. The trick is keeping it balanced and distributing the weight as evenly as possible across the various layers of the application.

Comment: I don't think my answer resembles any of the other answers here. There are *some* suggestions shared across the answers, but my answer as a whole is entirely different. If I feel like the provided answers are incomplete or I feel like I can contribute something unique, then I'll post an answer. Not really sure how your comment applies, honestly.

Comment: Methodically parsing through everyones answers, taking snippets, and putting them into my own words sounds like a lot of work. Clearly you took the time to do that when comparing my answer to the others though, so kudos to you. I didn't even notice. I'm sorry that my complete answer bothers you so much.

Answer (score 1):

It was probably due to poor design, and yes you should be concerned if you plan on getting heavier traffic or scaling the site.
Connection strings should be stored in `web.config`. Seems like you would have to do some redesigning of the data-layer and how the pages pass data to each other to steer away from storing datatables and datasets in Session. For example, instead of storing a whole dataset in Session, store, or pass by url, something small (like an ID) that can be used to re-query the database.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions always hurt scalability. However, once sessions are being used, the impact of a little bit more data in a session isn't that bad.

Still, it has to be stored somewhere, has to be retrieved from somewhere, so it's going to have an impact. It's going to really hurt if you have to move to a web-farm to deal with being very successful, since that's harder to do well in a scalable manner. I'd start by taking anything that should be global in the true sense (shared between all sessions) and move it into a truly globally-accessible location.

Then anything that depended upon the previous request, I'd have be sent by that request.

Doing both of those would reduce the amount they were used for immensely (perhaps enough to turn off sessions and get the massive scalability boost that gives).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the IIS version, using Session to store state can have an impact on scaling. The later versions of IIS are better.
However, the main problem I have run into is that sessions expire and then your data is lost; you may provide your own Session_OnEnd handler where it is possible to regenerate your session.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in feeling concerned about this.

Connection strings should be stored in Web.config and always read from there. The `Web.config` file is cached, so storing things in there and then on `Session` is redundant and unnecessary. The same can be said for locations of files: you can probably create key,value pairs in the `appSettings` section of your web.config to store this information.

As far as storing datasets, datatables, etc; I would only store this information on `Session` if getting them from the database is really expensive and provided the data is not too big. A lot of people tend to do this kind of thing w/o realizing that their queries are very fast and that database connections are pooled.

If getting the data from the database does take long, the first thing I would try to remedy would be the speed of my queries. Am I missing indexes? What does the execution plan of my queries show? Am I doing table scans, etc., etc.

One scenario where I currently store information on `Session` (or `Cache`) is when I do have to call an external web service that takes more than 2 secs on average to retrieve what I need. Once I get this data I don't need to getting again on every page hit, so I cache it.

Obviously an application that stores pretty much everything it can on `Session` is going to have scalability issues because memory is a limited resource.

Answer (score 0):

Overall yes, you should be concerned about this.

Session is a "per user" type of storage that is in memory.  Looking at the memory usage of the ASP.NET Worker Process will give you an idea of memory usage, but you might need to use third-party tools if you want to dig in deeper to what is in.  In addition session gets really "fun" when you start load balancing etc.

ConnectionStrings and other information that is not "per user" should really not be handled in a "per user" storage location.

As for creating a solution for this though, a lot is going to depend on the data itself, as you might need to find multiple other opportunities/locations to get/store the info.

Answer (score 0):

if memory is the issue, why not change session mode to sql server so you can store session data in sql server which requires little code changes.

how to store session data in sql server:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

the catch is that the classes stored in sql server must be serializable and you can use json.net to do just that.